# How can I add (append) a word to the same sentence, using one button (click) per word

Tags: c#

I greatly appreciate any help. I have 20+ buttons, each with a word, or a space or period. Each time I click on a button, the pre-existing word is wiped out and replaced with the new word. I need each word and/or space to remain in place until I click the "Clear" button.

Maybe this has been previously asked/answered under different search terms? I tend to believe I need to identify a string variable, but have no idea how to begin.

==============

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class frmSentenceBuilder : Form
    {
        public frmSentenceBuilder()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmSentenceBuilder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnA.Text;
        }

        private void btn_a_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btn_a.Text;
        }

        private void btnAn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnAn.Text;
        }

        private void btn_an_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btn_an.Text;
        }

        private void btnThe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnThe.Text;
        }

        private void btn_the_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btn_the.Text;
        }

        private void btnman_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnman.Text;
        }

        private void btnwoman_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnwoman.Text;
        }

        private void btndog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btndog.Text;
        }

        private void btncat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btncat.Text;
        }

        private void btncar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btncar.Text;
        }

        private void btnbicycle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnbicycle.Text;
        }

        private void btnbeautiful_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnbeautiful.Text;
        }

        private void btnbig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnbig.Text;
        }

        private void btnsmall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnsmall.Text;
        }

        private void btnstrange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnstrange.Text;
        }

        private void btnlookedat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnlookedat.Text;
        }

        private void btnrode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnrode.Text;
        }

        private void btnspoketo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnspoketo.Text;
        }

        private void btnlaughedat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnlaughedat.Text;
        }

        private void btndrove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btndrove.Text;
        }

        private void btnSpace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = " ";
        }

        private void btnperiod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnperiod.Text;
        }

        private void btnexclam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = btnexclam.Text;
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `lb1SentenceText.Text+=whatever.Text;`.

+= is equivalent to `lbSentence.Text = lblSentenceText.Text + whatever.Text`.

Basically, it appends or concatenates the right hand side `string` to the `string` on the left hand side. Hope it makes sense?

So:

```
string rhs="Hello " ;
string lhs = "World";
string rhs = rhs + lhs;//Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

Please be inspired.  You have a *lot* of redundant code.

```
    btnA.Click += AppendButtonText;
    btn_a.Click += AppendButtonText;
    ...


    private void AppendButtonText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            lblSentenceText.Text += button.Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I was told "don't worry about too much code for now.. just learn the processes".. taking my first C# class. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

On the button click events, change it to `+=` instead of `=` (except in the clear button). This is equivalent to writing `something = something + newValue;`.

Comment: Wow! So simple as +=? ..and yet for me seemed so difficult. Thank you so much. I am sure all of these responses make sense and I will study them all over the next few days. I searched all day using so many search term combos, but nothing like this! I am just getting started with C# so will strive to minimize code as I learn. I began to imagine surely I needed to introduce a string variable, but no. Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
lb1SentenceText.Text = lb1SentenceText.Text + *something*.text
```

The += operator means add to, and the variable modified is equal to the added (Int, String) appended to the original value (x = 1; x += 3; x is now 4)

Try this:

```
button.Click += new System.EventHandler(ButtonClick);
button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(ButtonClick);
// And for each button, one of those.
private void ButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
// Do whatever you want to do here, you can place the TEXT to be appended on the button, if so:
lb1SentenceText.Text += sender.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Simple.Create a global variable and within each button click event do this;

string yourStrVar = ""; //Must be global

yourStrVar+=  ((Button)sender).Text
```